# Nested for and if loops not working in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

There is a price report for many types products (copper). The report includes the name of products (Copper, Zinc, etc.) in one column, price in second column and it's corresponding date in the 3rd column.

I need to find in this report only Copper, then I need to take the prices for each date in a specific date range, and paste this price into another spreadsheet which also has dates, so when pasting the price, it should bee pasted into the correct row for that date.

I've managed to paste only one price, however it's not the correct date. I hope a screenshot will help understanding the task.

[image]

```
 Dim elements As Range, element As Range, dates_pnl As Range, x As Range
 Set elements = Workbooks("Metals_2019_11_21.csv").Worksheets("Metals_2019_11_21").Range("A2:A10")
 Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
 Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Prices")
 Set dates_pnl = ws1.Range("A771:A779")

 For Each element In elements
     If element.Value = "Copper" Then
         For Each x In dates_pnl
             If element.Offset(0, 1) = x Then
                 element.Offset(0, 2).Copy
                 ws1.Range("B772").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
             End If
         Next x
     End If
 Next element
```

Comment: Everything is being copied to the same cell (`ws1.Range("B772")`),  You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: I'd filter your source by Cooper, fill a dictionary with Dates as Key and price as items and then loop your destination worksheet to fill the dates with the dictionary.

Comment: @Damian, either that or a simple two-criteria `INDEX` + `MATCH`. You should post your idea as answer and I'll upvote that for sure. @OP, you could also try a worksheet-function if you want.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV but it's fine, he already got his answer and maybe mine would mess him more.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I will definitely improve the logic after I get the whole project running at least somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of copying is not the most efficient one, but it does the work. It's a good starting point.

```
Dim elements As Range, element As Range, dates_pnl As Range, x As Range
Set elements = Workbooks("Metals_2019_11_21.csv").Worksheets("Metals_2019_11_21").Range("A2:A10")
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Prices")
Set dates_pnl = ws1.Range("A771:A779")

For Each element In elements
    If element.Value = "Copper" Then
        For Each x In dates_pnl
            If element.Offset(0, 1) = x Then
                x.Offset(0, 1).Value = element.Offset(0, 2).Value
            End If
        Next 'x
    End If
Next 'element
```